# Dependencies for Firebird, Jaybird and Hibernate

Tags: java, firebird

I was interested to see the performance of Firebird with Hibernate, but I can not manage to make it run correctly. I added to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdparty-non-maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

When running it I keep getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
```

I tried adding all kinds of javax, javaee and others dependencies (via Maven), but I can't manage to run it. With PostgreSQL I have no issues and everything works as it is supposed to.

Running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.26.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the standard pom entry for Jaybird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'problem' is that Jaybird internally depends on the JavaEE concept of a resource-adapter and therefor requires some classes from JavaEE (specifically one that includes the javax.resource package (and subpackages). You need to include a JavaEE jar, or use

```
<groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5</version>
```

This one should automatically download the required dependency.

If all else fails, download the distribution from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/ and use the connector-api-1.5.jar from the lib folder.

BTW: I hope to eliminate this dependency in Jaybird 5.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of Jaybird

Comment: @Vojtěch Did you try using the dependency in my answer, did it work?

Comment: No, it did not make any difference, I had to add the jar manually.

Comment: @Vojtěch That is weird, I created http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-244 to investigate that further.

Comment: @Vojtěch Actually, I think I found the cause: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html **Last, any JAR file that contains Servlet API classes will be explicitly ignored by the classloader** The geronimo dependency that is used for maven instead of that mini-j2ee.jar also contains `javax.servlet` and is therefor entirely ignored.

Comment: @Vojtěch Just as a follow up: using the jaybird 2.1.6 in my post and excluding the geronimo dependency and including groupID: javax.resource, artifactId: connector-api, version: 1.5 as dependency also works

Answer (score 0):

We'll i was able to figure this out:

1. you can use hibernate's own connection pool
2. you can use commons-dbcp connection pool
3. you can use new tomcat7's jdbc connection pool.

Assuming you want to use 3, there are few steps you must perform, if you use firebird

1. Download jdk from : http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-jca-jdbc-driver/2.2.0-release-jdk16/Jaybird-2.2.0JDK_1.6.zip/download
2. Extract archive, copy jaybird*.jar and connector-api*.jar to /usr/share/tomcat7/lib.
   Inside the connector-api jar, there is the missing class ResourceException.

WARNING: do not copy huge j2eeapi.jar instead, beacuse they contain offending classes to servlet-api.jar from tomcat

1. If you installed tomcat7 from tar, that's all. If you use ubuntu apt to install tomcat's package, then download original tar from tomcat's download side, extract it and copy tomcat-jdbc to wherever is you tomcat's lib folder (for ubuntu, that is /usr/share/tomcat7/lib)

That's all. Put the configuration into context.xml and that's all

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/SOME_NAME"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testOnReturn="false"
    validationQuery="SELECT 'NOW' from RDB$DATABASE"
    validationInterval="30000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    maxActive="100"
    minIdle="10"
    maxWait="10000"
    initialSize="10"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
    jmxEnabled="true"
    jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
    username="sysdba"
    password="masterke"
    driverClassName="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"
    url="jdbc:firebirdsql:IP:ALIAS?lc_ctype=UTF-8"
/>
```